# How to convert datatime-local input to php variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to convert the input string to a data object of php, to use it on sql, but its not working and I can't find the error, the html is

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="interno">Fecha Limite</label>
    <input name="fechalimite" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fechalimite">
</div>
```

The post method on php does this

```
$fecha = getA(strtotime("fechalimite"));
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$fecha);
```

If I use echo fecha show the datetime right but the `$datetime` it is just blank, what I am missing?

**getA**

```
function getA($campo)
{
    return(htmlspecialchars(antiinjection($_REQUEST[$campo]), ENT_QUOTES));
}
```

Comment: Can we ask what `getA()` is doing

Comment: function getA($campo)

  {

   return(htmlspecialchars(antiinjection($_REQUEST[$campo]), ENT_QUOTES));

  }

Comment: Please provide some more details, "its not working" is not very descriptive. What's the content of `$datetime` afterwards, any error message (With all errors enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings/13402590)?

Comment: i said that $datetime is on blank

Comment: `print_r($fecha);` and tell us what it contains

Comment: Improve formatting and spelling

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a literal string of "fechalimite" to strtotime() which will return false.

Disregard your getA function and just pass the request variable to strtotime:

```
$fecha = strtotime($_REQUEST['fechalimite']);
```

There's absolutely no reason to try to encode HTML entities before passing a value to date().  You should only be encoding entities when generating output.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, its passing a string to `strtotime()`

```
$fecha = getA(strtotime("fechalimite"));
```

Try

```
$fecha = strtotime(getA("fechalimite"));
```

> although it looks like you are using `getA` as an anti SQL Injection mechanism.
>
> It is better to use parameterised bound queries for this